# change div text with ajax not working

Tags: c#, jquery, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc

What am I doing wrong?

I try to change div text with ajax... but doesn't do anything... I guess the problem is in my controller method..

**This my div**

```
<div id="div1">
   text to change
</div>

<button>change text</button>

@section scripts{
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("button").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Home/ChangeText", success: function (result) {
                    $("#Div1").html(result);
                }
            });
        });
        });
</script>
}
```

**This my Controller**

```
public JsonResult ChangeText()
{
    var result = "New Text";

    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

**Note: when is running it's enter to method 'ChangeText' but it doesn't print the result(New Text) on my view**

Comment: $("#Div1") should be $("#div1") - JS is case sensitive - also add `type="button"` to your buttons since some browsers will submit the page otherwise

Comment: Thanks... that was what I had bad....

Comment: @mplungjan This is not a case of _JavaScript_ being case sensitive, but of _HTML ids_ being case sensitive. In other circumstances it doesn't matter, e.g. with tag names. jQuery `$('DIV')` is fully equivalent to `$('div')`.

Comment: Still a case of case sensitivity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You wrote `<div id="div1">` and `$("#Div1").html(result);`. However `div1` not equals `Div1`, first symbol is big (upper case). JavaScript is sensitive to upper and lower case.

---

The type attribute specifies the type of button. Always specify the type attribute for the `<button>` element. Different browsers may use different default types for the `<button>` element. If you want send data to controller - write type of button `type="button"` or `type="submit"`.

Attribute values and descriptions:

1. `button` - *The button is a clickable button*
2. `submit` - *The button is a submit button (submits form-data)*
3. `reset` - *The button is a reset button (resets the form-data to its initial values)*

---

Try this code:

```
<div id="div1">
   text to change
</div>

<button type="button">change text</button>

@section scripts{
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("button").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Home/ChangeText", success: function (result) {
                    $("#div1").html(result); // Div1 != div1
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
}
```

Comment: Since you answered this typo - even when there was a comment already explaining the problem, OP cannot delete the question. Also WHEN answering, explain what you fixed along with the code.